# Using something similar to status.second with varStatus

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm working on something which assigns variables in a `<c:forTokens>` loop. Right now I'm using `varStatus` to assign the first and last item a different variable, but I'm wondering if there's something similar to status.second I can use? If I attempt to do so it throws an error.

This is what works currently:

```
<c:forTokens items="${position}" delims="||" var="slot" varStatus="status">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${status.first}">
            <c:set var="slotName" value="${slot}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${status.last}">
            <c:set var="dimensions" value="${slot}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="divName" value="${slot}" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forTokens>
```

What I want to do is something like this (adding in a third variable), but it throws an error:

```
<c:forTokens items="${position}" delims="||" var="slot" varStatus="status">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${status.first}">
            <c:set var="slotName" value="${slot}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${status.second}">
            <c:set var="posName" value="${slot}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${status.last}">
            <c:set var="dimensions" value="${slot}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="divName" value="${slot}" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forTokens>
```

What would be the right way to add a third variable to this?

Comment: `status.index == 1` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html

Comment: Well that was a lot easier than I expected.